# Printing Char Array Element

Tags: c, arrays

I've been hung up on this for the past two hours, and it's really starting to irritate me. I'm using standard C, trying to print a char array's element.

The following is a snippet that works(prints entire array),

```
CreditCard validate_card(long long n) {

    CreditCard cc; // specify new credit card
    cc.n = n; // specify card num as passed
    cc.valid = false; // initialize as invalid
    cc.type = AEX; // initialize at american express

    bool valid;

    char s[20];
    sprintf( s, "%d", n ); // convert credit card number into char array
    printf("%s\n", s);
    return cc;
}
```

The following snippet does not work,

```
CreditCard validate_card(long long n) {

    CreditCard cc; // specify new credit card
    cc.n = n; // specify card num as passed
    cc.valid = false; // initialize as invalid
    cc.type = AEX; // initialize at american express

    bool valid;

    char s[20];
    sprintf( s, "%d", n ); // convert credit card number into char array
    printf("%s\n", s[0]);
    return cc;
}
```

On that note, if anyone could also too explain to me how to concatinate char array elements to char pointers, I'd be grateful.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

When you use this line.

```
printf("%s\n", s[0]);
```

The compiler should print some warning about mismatch of the format string `%s` and the corresponding argument, `s[0]`.

The type of `s[0]` is `char`, not `char*`.

What's your intention?

If you want to print just one character, use:

```
printf("%c\n", s[0]);
```

If you want to print the entire array of chracters, use:

```
printf("%s\n", s);
```

Comment: Using native compiler on Ubuntu, it wasn't throwing me any errors or exceptions, so I was having a hard time dubugging the issue. I'd guessed it could've been the format, but quickly overlooked and started ravaging for another solution. Thank you for the insight.

Comment: You can use `-Wall` option to see all warnings.

Answer (score 2):

You need to replace below line

```
printf("%s\n", s[0]);
```

with

```
printf("%c\n", s[0]);
```

to print 1 character.

To print all characters 1 by 1, use a loop.

Answer (score 1):

If you need to print only the first character of the array, you need to use `%c`, like

```
printf("%c\n", s[0]);
```

Take a look at [this MSDN reference](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hf4y5e3w%28v=vs.100%29.aspx)